# Exporting an array to feed data to separate component

Tags: react-native

I have dataset, which looks like this:

```
    var items = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'foo',
          email: 'foo'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'foo',
          email: 'foo'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'foo',
          email: 'foo'
        },

      ];

  module.exports = items;
```

I'm feeding this data to searchable dropdown, so the data will be visible within the dropdown

The dropdown component, looks like this:

```
 <SearchableDropdown
                onItemSelect={(item) => {
                    const items = this.state.selectedItems;
                    items.push(item)
                    this.setState({ selectedItems: items });
                }}
                containerStyle={{ padding: 5 }}
                onRemoveItem={(item, index) => {
                    const items = this.state.selectedItems.filter((sitem) => sitem.id !== item.id);
                    this.setState({ selectedItems: items });
                }}
                itemStyle={{
                    padding: 10,
                    marginTop: 2,
                    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
                    borderColor: '#bbb',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderRadius: 5,
                }}
                itemTextStyle={{ color: '#222' }}
                itemsContainerStyle={{ maxHeight: 140 }}
                items={items}
                defaultIndex={null}
                resetValue={false}
                textInputProps={
                    {
                        placeholder: "Choose priority level",
                        underlineColorAndroid: "transparent",
                        style: {
                            padding: 12,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: '#ccc',
                            borderRadius: 5,
                        },
                        onTextChange: text => console.log(text)
                    }
                }
                listProps={
                    {
                        nestedScrollEnabled: false,
                    }
                }
            />
        </Fragment>
```

And I imported the dataset with the following import:

```
import items  from '../components/items';
```

However I'm getting that element type is invalid excepted a string but got object, I've tried previous threads from stackoverflow however nothing seems to solve my problem. Perhaps I'm missing something small that my eyes can't pick up? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to export the array as variable like

**items.js**

```
export const items = [
...
...
]
```

import it into your `component.js` like as

```
import {items} from '../path/to/items';
```

Just for confirmation log it inside your render method

```
console.log('Array Items', item);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This does help exporting the data to the different component however react native app whines about the data being an object, any ideas?